# Statistical differences between proportion percentages of multiple groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have data about 3 categories of people and the frequency distribution percentages of how many times some people belonging to these categories have visited one of three restaurants over a certain period of time:

```
observation group_type  place1  place2  place3  

1   A   0.25    0.25    0.5
2   A   0.3     0.4     0.3
3   B   0.1     0.2     0.7
4   B   0.2     0.2     0.6
5   B   0       0.1     0.9
6   C   0.3     0.3     0.4
7   C   0.3     0.1     0.6
8   C   0.2     0.2     0.6
```

Sample size may differ between observations but is not known. For instance observation 1 may be based on the actions of 100 people of category A and observation 2 may be based on the actions of 200 people. However how many people were observed each time is not known.

The dataset I gave is just a sample, but I have a relatively large number of observations (n > 1000) for each group. What I'm trying to compare is really the structure of the observations in each category. i.e. The observations happen at different times, and if there are 500 observations for A with 100 people and 500 observations for A with 1000 people, what I really care about in each case is the proportion of people that went to place 1 or place 2.

Would I be correct in:

1. Basing my comparison on the means of each proportion for each group? So, using the toy dataset above as an example, for place 1, comparing the mean of A (0.275) with that of B (0.1) for instance
2. Using a Mann-Whitney U test to test whether the difference between the means of each group is significantly different for the two others for each of the three places ?

Comment: It obviously makes a difference to the significance of the differences as to whether each is based on $1000$ people each time or $10$ (or $4$ in the first row).  Nor can you justify using a $0.275$ number if you do not have the sizes of the two A samples.

Comment: I understand that and maybe I should have given more details. The dataset I gave is just a sample, but I happen to have a relatively large number of observations (n > 1000) for each group. 
What I'm trying to compare is really the structure of the observations in each category. i.e. The observations happen at different times, and if there are 500 observations for A with 100 people and 500 observations for A with 1000 people, what I really care about in each case is the proportion of the total amount of people that went to place 1 or place 2.

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.